# Understanding required for inserting "esri/dijit/analysis/AggregatePoints" or related esri digit widget functions for arcgis javascript

Tags: javascript, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcmap

Currently, my code looks a little something like this and my map displays fine from my desktop without the inclusion of **"esri/dijit/analysis/AggregatePoints" or related widgets.** Is there a specific position to insert the widget to ensure that my map still displays even after the inclusion?

```
require([
    // ArcGIS
    "esri/Map",
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/layers/MapImageLayer",  "esri/layers/TileLayer", "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",

  "esri/geometry/geometryEngine",
  "esri/Graphic",
  "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol","esri/symbols/SimpleMarkerSymbol", "esri/symbols/PictureMarkerSymbol", "esri/symbols/TextSymbol",
  "esri/geometry/SpatialReference",

    // Widgets
    "esri/widgets/BasemapGallery",
    "esri/widgets/Search",
    "esri/widgets/Legend",
    "esri/widgets/LayerList",
    "esri/widgets/BasemapToggle",
    "esri/widgets/ScaleBar",
    "esri/widgets/Popup",


    // Bootstrap
    "bootstrap/Collapse",
    "bootstrap/Dropdown",

    // Calcite Maps
    "calcite-maps/calcitemaps-v0.4",


    "dojo/domReady!"
],
```

Comment: The way you order required modules does not matter.

Comment: @BelowtheRadar then do you know why my would not display if i include it? as such? This still follows the spacing and whatnot provided by Javascript, where else would you suggest I insert the code in?

`require([
    // ArcGIS
    "esri/Map", "esri/dijit/analysis/AggregatePoints",
    "esri/views/MapView",
    "esri/layers/FeatureLayer", "esri/layers/MapImageLayer",  "esri/layers/TileLayer", "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer", `

Comment: `esri/dijit/analysis/AggregatePoints` is a module from the javascript API v3.x but it seems you are using the API v4.x. You have an error because AggregatePoints cannot be found in API v4.x